How to add badge at next file in solution explorer?
I'm working on a VSIX project. The function I'm currently developing is to express the badge next to the icon differently for each specific state of the file. How can I change the status of the icon or the status of the badge next to the icon in a specific file?

You tried to change it by attempting to access Property with IVsHierarchy, but VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL or VSConstants.DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND is returned.

public void UpdateOverlayIcon(params string[] paths)
{
    if (_hierarchy == null || _imageService == null) 
        return;

    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            continue;

        var icon = LoadIcon(path);
        var hierarchy = GetHierarchyFromFilePath(_hierarchy as IVsSolution, path, out uint itemId);

        var result = hierarchy.SetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_IconHandle, icon);

        if(result == VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL)
        {
             // returned VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL;
        }
        else if(result == VSConstants.DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND)
        {
             // returned VSConstants.DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}

private IntPtr LoadIcon(string path)
{
    var action = GetAction(path);
    var image = GetImage(action);
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(image);

    return bitmap.GetHicon();
}

public static Image GetImage(FileAction action)
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case FileAction.Add:
            return Images.add;
        case FileAction.Delete:
            return Images.delete;
        case FileAction.Edit:
            return Images.edit;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


public static IVsHierarchy GetHierarchyFromFilePath(IVsSolution solution, string filePath, out uint itemId)
{
    itemId = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;

    foreach (var hierarchy in GetAllProjects(solution))
    {
        var parsed = hierarchy.ParseCanonicalName(filePath, out itemId);

        if (parsed == VSConstants.S_OK)
            return hierarchy;
    }

    return null;
}

private static IEnumerable<IVsHierarchy> GetAllProjects(IVsSolution solution)
{
    var projects = new List<IVsHierarchy>();
    var guid = Guid.Empty;

    solution.GetProjectEnum(
        (uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_LOADEDINSOLUTION, 
        ref guid, 
        out IEnumHierarchies enumHierarchies);

    var hierarchy = new IVsHierarchy[1];

    while (enumHierarchies.Next(1, hierarchy, out uint fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK && fetched == 1)
        projects.Add(hierarchy[0]);

    return projects;
}

